# I Can't Put Image in PrimeReact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

[I want to add images to the dashboard using primereact but I can't. I put my photo folder in the public folder, but my photo did not appear on the page even though I entered the photo path. I tried several ways, but failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FAKn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I Find the way i forgot {} this true code like this;

```
<img src={'image path'} alt='.'>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).